# Sonata Admin custom action seems not using the custom controller

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to make a custom action but I'm gettin this error:

```
Controller "Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::editarDistribucionAction" for URI "/admin/test/tarifas/distribucionperiodos/6/distribucion/editar" is not callable.
```

I have reviewed the code many times but I can't find the mistake:

This is my custom controller:

```
class CustomActionsController extends CRUDController
{

    public function editarDistribucionAction(){
        //$id = $request->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

        //TODO:
    }
}
```

And this is my services.yml

```
  sonata.admin.editarDistribucion:
      class: Test\TarifasBundle\Admin\DistribucionPeriodosTablaAdmin
      tags:
          - name: sonata.admin
            manager_type: orm
            group: "Tarifas"
            label: "Distribución de periodos"
      arguments: [ null, Test\TarifasBundle\Entity\DistribucionPeriodosTabla, TarifasBundle:CustomActions ]
```

I have tried to put wrong parameters on services.yml expecting a different error, but i get exacly the same, so it seems that is ignoring this piece of services.yml

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It was a concept mistake. I followed the official doc step by step but y was mixing different admin clases. The configureRoutes code was in one class and I was trying to edit another one.